# Geo-coding - SyntaxError: can't assign to literal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, literals

When running the last two lines, it reports an error message as follows:

```
File "<stdin>", line 32
  SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

Any solution to this problem?

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
# location = geolocator.geocode("175 5th Avenue NYC")
# location = geolocator.geocode("berlin, germany")
location = geolocator.geocode("oxford street, london")
print(location.address)
print((location.latitude, location.longitude))

import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv("city5.csv")
# print(df)

import io
import sys
import urllib.request
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer,encoding='utf8') #改变标准输出的默认编码
res=urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.baidu.com')
htmlBytes=res.read()
# print(htmlBytes.decode('utf-8'))


df["Conca"]=df["city"]+", "+df["country"]
# print(df)

df["Coordinates"]=df["Conca"].apply(geolocator.geocode)
print(df)

print(df.columns)

print(df.Coordinates)
print(df.Coordinates[0].latitude)
df=["Ycor"]=df["Coordinates"].apply(lambda x: x.latitude if x != None else None)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df=["Ycor"]=df["Coordinates"].apply(lambda x: x.latitude if x != None else None)
```

You have an extra `=` in there. I'm sure you meant:

```
df["Ycor"]=df["Coordinates"].apply(lambda x: x.latitude if x != None else None)
```

Comment: BTW, I will have the problem of "UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character" if I do not import below code:                                                       import io
import sys
import urllib.request
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer,encoding='utf8') 
res=urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.baidu.com')
htmlBytes=res.read()            ---------------what are the simpler way to solve the charater formatting issue?

Comment: That's a separate problem, which you should ask about in a separate question.